# (FrameLayout) findViewById - returns null?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

Why do I always  (FrameLayout) findViewById  always returns null?
The file exists.
Working with Google Maps.
I read the related topics.
Powered by:
Project-Clean.
Delete folder gen.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.travel_map_activity);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.travelMapView);

    FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapFrame);//null

}
```

What's the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:text="FLOATING VIEW - TOP"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout></FrameLayout>
```

travel_map_activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/travelMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="key" />

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: Is that `travel_map_activity.xml`? I feel like it's not, due to referencing `R.id.travelMapView` on the line above.

Comment: travel_map_activity.xml added in post.

Answer (score 0):

Are those two Views you are finding (`travelMapView` and `mapFrame`) in the same layout `travel_map_activity`. Because the layout you provided isn't holding `travelMapView` at all, yet you don't get a `NullPointerException` there.

**EDIT**: As you show right now, `mapFrame` is not in the same view, so there is no way to get to that...

*Well*, there is one, but it won't be useful, as `setContentView` only shows up **one** single layout at a time. Anyway, you *could* still access `mapFrame` with an inflated layout, without it being actually used (and that's because it is **completely useless**):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.your_other_layout_with_framelayout, null );
FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mapFrame);
```

Using this will let you escape from that null, but **again**, there's no chance you can use that FrameLayout if it isn't in your current view.

Comment: I have not shown all the code that pops up only when NullPointerException FrameLayout.

Comment: Check Eric's answer and my edit. And please, please, read **carefully** both answers

Answer (score 0):

You're inflating the layout from `travel_map_activity.xml`, which only contains one ID: `R.id.travelMapView`. You cannot select items from other layouts (*with a few small exceptions that are more like abuses of the system*).

You either need to set the content view to whichever layout it is that contains `R.id.mapFrame`, or you need to find another way to pass that data in (probably using a `Bundle` packaged with the `Intent` with `.putExtra()` and `.getIntExtra()`, for example; there are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308232/passing-data-through-intent-and-receiving-it) and [blogs](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/) that cover this kind of thing).

Comment: you aren't giving a nice answer