# Can't access ArrayList in other view? android null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to access an ArrayList of Integers from a previous class that was set in the previous view however it doesn't seem to be saving the arrayList correctly when I go to the new view I think it deletes whatever was there?

Is there anyway to access the "lightInfo" that was already set?

ConnectTest declaration

```
public class ConnectTest extends MainActivity {
    TextView out;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;

    // Well known SPP UUID
    private static final UUID MY_UUID =
            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // Insert your server's MAC address
    private static String address = "A4:5E:60:EB:3C:E8";
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = ((MainActivity) getApplicationContext()).lightInfo;
```

Call to temp that creates the error:

```
 String finalMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            finalMessage = finalMessage + temp.get(i) + "\n";
        }

        String message = finalMessage;
```

MainActivity declaration

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    UUID myUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    private static final int DISCOVER_DURATION = 300;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLU = 1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<Double> currentBodyTemp;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    boolean targetTimeZoneIsAhead = false;
    boolean targetTimeZoneIsBehind = false;

    int currentWakeTime = 420;
    int currentSleepTime = 1320;

    int targetWakeTime = 0;
    int targetSleepTime = 0;
    int daysLeft = 0;
    int timeDifference = 0;

    public ArrayList<Integer> lightInfo;
```

Error Message:

```
10-27 12:59:56.141 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4, PID: 15803
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.ConnectTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:111)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4.ConnectTest.<init>(ConnectTest.java:34)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1684)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2954)
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
10-27 12:59:56.151 15803-15803/com.teamfara.circadianrhythmmonitor4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply typecast any object and expect it to work. Please use proper data passing mechanisms. Try this:

[Passing data through Intent and receiving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308232/passing-data-through-intent-and-receiving-it)

Answer (score 0):

your app is crashing because your are trying to access `getApplicationContext` in the global scope of your Activity while, this  latter didn't go through its lifecycle. Since your `ConnectTest` extends your `MainActivity` you don't any cast to access any ***not-private*** member of  `MainActivity`. You only need to mark is as `public` or `protected`. Even the default access specifier is good if the two classes are in the same package. Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)